# C# can't find properties file, how do I repair this?

Tags: c#, installation

I had a Properties file called `RecentFileList` within my Visual Studio 2012 project and I removed it. I believe it was a `.settings` file. Now when I run my setup project, it is trying to copy files that it shouldn't care about and it's bombing out as a result. I get 3 errors (-1007 -6271 and -6103), all related to the same missing file.

```
-6103: Could not find file "C:\Users\Charles\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RallyCourses\RallyCourseDesigner\bin\Debug\Properties\RecentFileList.Designer.cs
```

What file do I need to edit to get rid of the reference to this file? I tried searching for `RecentFileList.Designer.cs`, but can't find it.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning/rebuilding the project/solution? If that doesn't work you could go to the /bin/debug folder and manually delete everything, then build again.

Comment: OH CRAP! I tried Cleaning it and it brings up 29 more errors! Oh no, how am I going to fix these???

Comment: Side note: consider using source control system... Most people figure it out after hitting similar issues (lost a file/overwrote changes) for more than 9000 times, but you have good chance to save yourself from too much pain...

Comment: OK, I got rid of those extra 29 errors. I think they went away when I closed one of the windows. Understood about the source control, but that doesn't help me now....

Comment: I see some references in app.config, do I want to remove these? When I do, it doesn't seem to get rid of my error messages...hhhmmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending files in my situation were trying to be installed by the installer, but I had removed them from the main project. Within the SetUp project, there is a section `Specify Application Data -> Files`. I found the files in the Properties section there, removed them, and things are working now...